# How to refactor a simple long case statement

Tags: ruby, refactoring, case, sinatra, erb

So I created a drop-down form for my Sinatra project, and I want it to prepopulate the option. I was able to do that but it turned into a big case statement! Any Idea how to refactor this? Thanks!

```
get '/animes/:id/edit' do 
    if is_logged_in?
    @anime = Anime.find_by_id(params[:id])
    case @anime.rating
    when 1
        @oneselect = "selected"
    when 2
        @twoselect = "selected"
    when 3
        @threeselect = "selected"
    when 4
        @fourselect = "selected"
    when 5
        @fiveselect = "selected"
    when 6
        @sixselect = "selected"
    when 7
        @sevenselect = "selected"
    when 8
        @eightselect = "selected"
    when 9
        @nineselect = "selected"
    when 10
        @tenselect = "selected"
    end
    erb :'animes/edit'
    else
       redirect to '/' 
    end
end
```

And this is my .erb view file form!

```
 <label for="rating">Rating:</label>

<select name="rating" id="rating" value="<%=@anime.rating%>">
  <option value="10"<%=@tenselect%>>10 (Masterpiece)</option>
  <option value="9"<%=@nineselect%>>9 (Great)</option>
  <option value="8"<%=@eightselect%>>8 (Very Good)</option>
  <option value="7"<%=@sevenselect%>>7 (Good)</option>
  <option value="6"<%=@sixselect%>>6 (Fine)</option>
  <option value="5"<%=@fiveselect%>>5 (Average)</option>
  <option value="4"<%=@fourselect%>>4 (Bad)</option>
  <option value="3"<%=@threeselect%>>3 (Very Bad)</option>
  <option value="2"<%=@twoselect%>>2 (Horrible)</option>
  <option value="1"<%=@oneselect%>>1 (Appalling)</option>

</select><br>
```

Comment: Note the following: if  `h = { 1=>"one", 2=>"two",..., 10=>"ten" }` and `@oneselect = 'cat'` then `n=1; instance_variable_set("@#{h[n]}select" , 'dog') #=> "dog"` so now `@oneselect
 #=> "dog"`. I doubt very much, however, if you want all those instance variables, as opposed to one variable that holds an array of `10` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, I don't know anything about Sinatra, so this answer may be off base.

If I were looking at this code for myself, I would be thinking along the lines of doing something like (not tested, and my erb is a bit rusty):

```
<label for="rating">Rating:</label>

<%
options = [
  [10, '10 (Masterpiece)'],
  [9, '9 (Great)'],
  [8, '8 (Very Good)'],
  [7, '7 (Good)'],
  [6, '6 (Fine)'],
  [5, '5 (Average)'],
  [4, '4 (Bad)'],
  [3, '3 (Very Bad)'],
  [2, '2 (Horrible)'],
  [1, '1 (Appalling)']
]
%>

<select name="rating" id="rating">
<% options.each do |option| %>
  <option value="<%= option[0].to_s %>"<%= @anime.rating == option[0] ? ' selected' : '' %>><%= option[1] %></option>
<% end %>
</select><br>
```

and then remove the case statement.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you, it worked! Can you please explain to me the logic of how this code works? Sorry, I am new to coding!

Comment: Hi Katie, I feel like there's probably a better way to say this but ...

I think that the logic is that for each item in the options array (in the order specified in the array) we're going to output an <option> tag. This option tag has a value attribute set from the first element of the current item from the options array and content from the second element of the current item. The selected attribute gets set based on whether the current item's first element matches the value of @anime.rating; it does this by making use of the ternary operator, if you've not come across that before.

Comment: Yes, I know about ternary operator; I just don't quite understand why after selected, the other option is an empty string? And at the end is option[1]? I get that you'd have to iterate, just not understanding that line of iteration!

Comment: The ternary operator requires three parts, the conditional statement at the start and then (after the ?) the value to give if the conditional statement was true and the (after the :) the value if the conditional statement was false; I don't think you can have a ternary operator without all of those three things. Given that we don't want anything to be output in the case of no match with the rating an empty string will do that for us.

Comment: As we go through each item in the options list we assign the value of that item to the option variable. This variable then contains an array, e.g. [10, '10 (Masterpiece)'] for the first instance, [9, '9 (Great)'] for the second etc. To access the 10 (for first item) from this array we use option[0]; to access the '10 (Masterpiece)' we use option[1]. We output the option[1] as the content of the <option> HTML tag so that it displays as the label for the option. Hopefully that helps, but I feel like I might have not understood the question.

Comment: Okay, I 90% get it now! Haha. Thanks :) Sorry one last question, if they wanted to access other options, they will do so after accessing the option[1], correct? Like, the selected option that the user have chosen. Since it wont always be option[1]

Comment: I'm making a bunch of assumptions here but ... The selected attribute should determine the selected option on page load. From there the user should be able to change which option is selected in the select HTML element. For that to be saved (most likely) some kind of posting of the form needs to happen back to the server to set the '@anime.rating' value to whatever the user chose when they changed the select value. Upon reopening the edit page '@anime.rating' should have whatever value was saved to it and so the select box should be displaying whatever the user chose before they last saved.

Answer (score 0):

A useful object might be a map from the numerical rating to its string representation:

```
@ratings_map = {
  1 => "1 (Appalling)",
  2 => "2 (Horrible)",
  3 => "3 (Very Bad)",
  etc...
}
```

Rather than passing a separate variable for every rating (@oneselect, @twoselect, etc), you can simply use @anime itself for the selected value. Then, you can use the options_for_select helper function:

```
<label for="rating">Rating:</label>

<%= options_for_select(@ratings_map.map{|key, value| [value, key]}, @anime.rating) %>
```

Some useful documentation on the options_for_select helper:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

**Edit:**
My apologies, had my head in Rails land. If you're using Sinatra, you would have to explicitly `require 'active_support'` at the top of your Sinatra application for this solution to work. You would also want to make sure active_support is included in your Gemfile, and `bundle install`